# I want to install pip for python3.6. When i allready have another version of python3 is installed.

Tags: python, pip

But when i run command sudo apt-get install python3-pip. It is installed but inot as python3.6. It is installed in python3.5.I have also specified the version in command i.e sudo apt-get install python3.6-pip.But it gives me an error.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.6-pip
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.6-pip'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.6-pip'

Answer (score 2):

You can install python packages using `python3.6 -m pip install [Package_to_install]` straight away.

Comment: i get error : /usr/local/bin/python3.6: No module named pip

Answer (score 1):

I use [PipEnv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) for working in different environments with different python versions.

the usage would be something like `pipenv --python 3.X` and it will install that version of python if its not installed.

It also makes things really helpful if you are collaborating with other developers, because it creates a PipFile (alt to `requirements.pip`) which will contain the version of python used for the project so all developers will use the same version of python on a project without doing any prep work.

If you don't want to use pipenv you can use pip3.5 or create a python3.5 environment like `virtualenv [NAME] --python=/usr/lib/python3.5` and then install the package using `pip install somepackage`

Comment: pip and pip3 configured with python2.7 and python3.5 respectively. But have project which requires python3.6 . So how to configure pip3 with python3.6 instead of python3.5. I can't remove python 3.5. I am using ubuntu 16.0.4

Comment: You can always run `pipenv --python 3.6` or `virtualenv [NAME] --python=/usr/lib/python3.X` to whatever version of python you need. You just need to ensure that version of python is installed.

Answer (score 0):

It was easy. I just changed my default python3 version:
`sudo gedit ~/.bashrc  alias python3="python3.6"`

Now I  can install the packages using python3.6 with
`-m pip install 'packagenae'`

Answer (score 0):

This will help you fix the above problem

You need to add following personal package repository:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`

Check for updates
`sudo apt-get update`

install python using following command
`sudo apt-get install python3.6`